# Can not resolve DNS on Ubuntu 20.04 on specific network

Tags: networking, dns, systemd-resolved

I am having trouble resolving DNS only at my parents place which I really do not understand. It is the only place where I have that problem.

My feeling is that `systemd-resolved` is not configured properly.
When I use the "broken" wifi I see A LOT of these messages:

```
Using degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server 192.168.0.1.
```

As soon as I switch to my hotspot there just a couple of them.

Here is my `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
```

Here my `resolvectl status`

```
resolvectl status --no-pager                                                                                   
Global
       LLMNR setting: no                  
MulticastDNS setting: no                  
  DNSOverTLS setting: no                  
      DNSSEC setting: no                  
    DNSSEC supported: no                  
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa     
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      corp                
                      d.f.ip6.arpa        
                      home                
                      internal            
                      intranet            
                      lan                 
                      local               
                      private             
                      test                

Link 5 (docker0)
      Current Scopes: none
DefaultRoute setting: no  
       LLMNR setting: yes 
MulticastDNS setting: no  
  DNSOverTLS setting: no  
      DNSSEC setting: no  
    DNSSEC supported: no  

Link 4 (br-4d2c8a375e85)
      Current Scopes: none
DefaultRoute setting: no  
       LLMNR setting: yes 
MulticastDNS setting: no  
  DNSOverTLS setting: no  
      DNSSEC setting: no  
    DNSSEC supported: no  

Link 3 (wlo1)
      Current Scopes: DNS        
DefaultRoute setting: yes        
       LLMNR setting: yes        
MulticastDNS setting: no         
  DNSOverTLS setting: no         
      DNSSEC setting: no         
    DNSSEC supported: no         
  Current DNS Server: 192.168.0.1
         DNS Servers: 192.168.0.1
          DNS Domain: ~.         
                      fritz.box  

Link 2 (enp2s0)
      Current Scopes: none
DefaultRoute setting: no  
       LLMNR setting: yes 
MulticastDNS setting: no  
  DNSOverTLS setting: no  
      DNSSEC setting: no  
    DNSSEC supported: no
```

I can ping public internet:

```
ping 8.8.8.8                                                                                                                                                                                              
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=116 time=48.6 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=116 time=41.1 ms
```

I have enabled `debug` logging for `systemd-resolvd` since this is my hunch but could be wrong.

https://pastebin.com/hAbb8ApS

Happy for any hints!

Comment: Look at the network logs: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl systemd-dnsmasq`.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://superuser.com/questions/1676584/using-degraded-feature-set-tcp-instead-of-udp-for-dns-server  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I do not have `dnsmasq` running.

`NetworkManager` looks pretty okay from my first glance:

https://pastebin.com/jMkt9DqR

Comment: When enabling ipv6 on that router, I can browse and use DNS for ipv6 things only. There is no CG NAT here. Plain old dual-stack as of now.

Comment: I suggest that you set fixed DNS nameservers in Network Manager: https://storage.googleapis.com/static.configserverfirewall.com/images/ubuntu/nm-dns.png

Comment: @chili555 I tried this as well. Still the same behavior.